# 3 .h and 3 .cpp files

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I'm building an application that should use one class from 1.h in 2.h it is defined like:

```
<classname> *p;
```

now i can use p in 2.cpp. But I would also like to use it in 3.cpp. I could not include the 2.h in 3.cpp. Is there a way to make it visible in 3.cpp?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please explain why you "could not include the 2.h in 3.cpp". Because that should be the answer to your question.

Comment: You can include any `.h` in any `.cpp`. Otherwise you are doing something horribly wrong.

Comment: Dos you .h files define the _interface_ of the corresponding .cpp files? When you just define such an interface you should be able to solve the problem.

Comment: More generalisations. Cut the notation and put in sample code with Foos and Bars if necessary or A B and C

Comment: I like the game of substituting actual information with meta-information, so instead of speaking of a specific class we substitute it for <classname>, instead of **what** 2 headers, we speak of 2 headers, now the next level is: Say we have a source-code f(x) in some language Y where x is the byte-index we want to perform operation Z on the 2 data-sources, and suppose some error E occurs, how can we solve this problem?

Comment: I prefer, when showing a problem, to give a duplication of the actual issue with code that might compile, and that you can test against. <classname> looks either like an STL header (it isn't) or some kind of template parameter (it isn't that either).

Answer (score 0):

A more descriptive example of your problem with some code would be valuable.

In general attempt to do the following:

- Each header should contain only the its own class with the same name.
- If a class is using another class, and you can forwardly declare it in that header, do.

You cannot forwardly declare if the class has an instance of another class or if it derives from it.

- Compilation units (cpp) files should include all the headers they need. Ideally include its own header first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more info but I think I got it
Your trying to use a class in a header that was defined I. A another header, but for some reason you can't include the header it was defined into the header your working on. The solution is to create a "temporary" definition instead of an include.

Eg:
U need myClassA in 1.h but it was defined in 2.h and some error doesn't let you include 2.h into 1.h to solve it you.simply
Write:

class myClassA;

on top of 1.h so you can reference it, but no implementation (because it is implemented in 2.cpp)

Answer (score 0):

A simple rule is one class, one header file.

Given:

```
A.h:
class A
{
};

B.h:
#include "A.h"
class B
{
  A obj;
};

C.h:
#include "A.h"
class C
{
  A obj;
};
```

I hope this answers the question.  Otherwise, edit your question with more details and example of what you are trying to accomplish.